# Why this labeledPolygon is not working?

Tags: fabricjs

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumo/9k072jd5/)

I am drawing a diamond as a polygon but its not working.. The output should be a diamond with blue fill with a label "B" in the middle.

```
var labeledPolygon = new LabeledPolygon([
    {x: (xX), y: (yY+r)},
    {x: (xX+r), y: (yY)},
    {x: (xX+2*r), y: (yY+r)},
    {x: (xX+r), y: (yY+2*r)}], {
        originX: 100,
        originY: 100,
        label: t,
        fill: 'blue'
    });
canvas.add(labeledPolygon);
```

The code after the coordinates is not working..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check tutorial for more information http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#subclassing

Comment: also check polygon initial declaration http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html#initialize

Answer (score 0):

Your initialize method has only "options" as argument, but you are passing "polygonPoints" and "options" as arguments. Therefore your initialize method should look like this

```js
 initialize: function (polygonPoints, options) {
  polygonPoints || (polygonPoints = {});
  options || (options = {});

  this.callSuper('initialize', polygonPoints, options);
  this.set('label', options.label || '');
 },
```